# Do different CPUs with same architecture use same complier？

Tags: architecture, compiler-construction, arm, cpu, qualcomm

For example, do different processors with the same armv8 architecture use one same compiler?
More specifically, do Qualcomm and MTK processors use the same compiler?

Comment: processors dont use compilers, programmers use compilers and are free to choose which compiler they want to use for a particular target (there are many different choices for qualcomm for example that any one user can choose).

Comment: What do you mean by "the same compiler"? The same executable? Probably not, unless the processors and the operating systems are very similar. Or do you mean compilers compiled from the same source code? Both GCC and Clang run on a huge variety of platforms, so with that definition, certainly.

Comment: the instruction set is only a tiny part of the problem, it is like choosing a language/alphabet, only gets relevant when you want to say something.  if they have the same core/instruction set then you can use the same tools if you wish of course, but the real meat of the programs/operating system have zero to do with the instruction set, they are about peripherals which are different from one SoC to another so the libraries for those will be different...

Comment: it is like the difference between a math book and a chemistry book, you can use the same language/alphabet (instrucion set) but that is almost irrelevant to the topic/meat of the book...which are not interchangeable because they are different topics.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the processors are capable of compiling from the same target triple, code generated for one of the processors should be capable of running on the other.

A Target Triple is a specifier for a set of properties a target has, such as its architecture (x86_64, armv8, armhf etc), vendor and its ABI. Clang has a decent description of how a target triple is determined and which properties are relevant. A link to that article can be found here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html#target-triple